# Drupal 8 block cached, but the expensive call still runs

Tags: blocks

So I created a custom block like this:

```
  public function build() {
    $output = [
      '#cache' => [
        'keys' => ['bix_salary_jobs'],
        'contexts' => ['url.path'],
        'tags' => ['bix_salary_jobs'],
        'max-age' => 60 * 60 * 24 * 7
      ]
    ];

    // expensive call comes here.
    $data = expensive_all();
    $output['data'] = $data;
    return $output;
```

From the browser, I can see this block is cached, because the same content has shown there. If cache is not enabled, i.e, if `#cache` is removed, the content will be different.

Now my question is since this block has been rendered using the cache, why this expensive call `expensive_all();` is still running every time this page refreshes? I can see it runs because I put a `var_dump("call runs")` inside `expensive_all();`. This message always shows when page refreshes.

My assumption is since this block has been cached, those expensive call inside this block could be avoided, and that's the purpose of cache. If this expensive call still runs with cache, then this block cache becomes useless.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have disabled caching for debugging purpose? Other than that you don't need to build a cacheable render array with cache keys, because the block has one already, so it is enough to return the contexts/tags/max-age. But if you want to build such a cacheable element then put the expensive to calculate function in a `#pre_render` callback. See https://dev.acquia.com/blog/drupal-8-performance-render-caching

Comment: Sounds like you might be calling expensive_all() elsewhere in your code. Try putting a var_dump or something within the build() code you've provided. If thats not getting triggered then something else is calling your expensive_all function

Comment: @Leigh, `var_dump()` is put inside `build()`, and it has been called too.

Comment: Then it sounds like you dont have block caching enabled and what you thought was drupal's caching may have just been your browser caching. Have you disabled caching via a settings.local.php? Or perhaps something within your code/a module thats disabling it. As if that block is actually getting cached you wouldnt be seeing your dump

Comment: @Leigh, I had the same assumption with you. Not sure why it works like this. The cached content can be served as stated in the question body.

Comment: @4k4, I tried to use `#pre_render` and get the similar results. This result from this callback seems not cacheable as long as it takes effect.

Comment: Anyway, I end up writing custom cache set/get to cache the expensive call results. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: OK, but the code is OK, you don't even need cache keys and #pre_render. I think this is a debugging issue and you get a cached version of var_dump() as @Leigh explained, either from the browser cache or from the Drupal page cache. To be sure try to debug this with Xdebug.